# Apply condition on subset of df columns and return sum and % of total of other column

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I'm experiencing a frustrating problem that I should, but have been unable to, solve. Given a dataframe like below, I would like to return, for every week W1 through W4, the amount and the amount percentage from the "amount" column based on a simple condition. The dataset also contains NAs which need to be ignored for the calculations.

I have attempted to write a function with two parameters to first get the IDs that are above my condition (100) and then do the division in amount. Here are my laughable efforts.

```
myfxn=function(x, y, na.rm=TRUE) {
  count=x>100
  with(count,100*(sum(y,na.rm=na.rm)/sum(!is.na(y)))) 
}

zz=as.data.frame(sapply(exampledata[3:6], myfxn, y=exampledata[2]))

structure(list(ID = 1:10, amount = c(200L, 100L, 300L, 400L, 
500L, 200L, 200L, 250L, 150L, 300L), W1 = c(150L, NA, 192L, 143L, 
158L, 187L, 173L, NA, 123L, NA), W2 = c(198L, 36L, 86L, 47L, 
38L, 109L, 196L, 17L, 188L, NA), W3 = c(50L, 36L, 70L, NA, 45L, 
164L, 82L, 169L, 113L, 89L), W4 = c(124L, 18L, 133L, NA, 162L, 
23L, 65L, 153L, 145L, 173L)), .Names = c("ID", "amount", "W1", 
"W2", "W3", "W4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Ideally, my return would be a df with 4 rows (W1:W4) and 2 columns (Amount and Amount as %). Thank you for your help!

Comment: hi tony :) again i dont understand 100% what you want but I will try to give you a solution, it comes down to changing from wide to long again, doing your calculation and then spreading again; what is your condition? that the week value is above 100 ? and the % of what from what do you want?

Comment: Hi, you're a savior until I learn how to do these variations myself. My condition is week value above 100, yes. And the % is the (sum of IDs that are more than 100) divided by (sum of all non-NA IDs in that week)

Comment: sry I dont quite understand the sum of IDs part, what are the values in the week-columns? do you want the sum of the weeks divided by the amount for each ID ??  the first part is exactly the same thing I showed you yesterday, which is: `gather(df, Week, Value, 3:6) %>% filter(Value > 100)`

Comment: Sorry, the sum of amounts***. So for Week 1, the plain sum of amounts greater than 100 would be 2050 (all of them minus the 2 NA amount values), while the percentage would be 100% because the total sum of non-NA amounts is also 2050

Comment: i am beginning to understand....

Comment: Okay. Let me know if anything else is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution, which is kinda long-winded but it works, a faster solution would involve more complicated code and or other packages, but this solution here is simple only using dplyr/tidyr/magrittr I hope I understood you correctly:

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
gather(df, Week, Value, 3:6) %>% filter(Value > 100) %>%
    group_by(Week) %>% summarise(Sum.amounts.per.week.over100 = sum(amount)) ->
    t.week.over100

gather(df, Week, Value, 3:6) %>%
    group_by(Week) %>% filter(!is.na(Value)) %>%
    summarise(Sum.amounts.per.week.total = sum(amount)) -> t.week.total

t.week <- merge(t.week.over100, t.week.total, by = "Week")
t.week$percent <- t.week$Sum.amounts.per.week.over100/t.week$Sum.amounts.per.week.total * 100
```

if you want the percent rounded:

```
t.week$percent <- round(t.week$percent)
```

I strongly advise you to look at a couple of tutorials about tidyr/dplyr and magrittr, especially the first two, for example:

[intro to dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

[intro to tidyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/)

[intro to magrittr](http://seananderson.ca/2014/09/13/dplyr-intro.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, and you understood correctly. Yes, I need to go through those asap. Really appreciate your patience.